# How to check if the Google Drive file is shared with anyone having the link to the file with Google Drive API?

Tags: php, yii, google-api, google-drive-api, google-client

I am writing an API to check if the Google Drive file is shared with anyone having the link. I have File ID of a Google Drive file. I have a code snippet to print the permission of the file

```
function printPermission($service, $fileId, $permissionId) {
  try {
    $permission = $service->permissions->get($fileId, $permissionId);

    print "Name: " . $permission->getName();
    print "Role: " . $permission->getRole();
    $additionalRoles = $permission->getAdditionalRoles();
    if(!empty($additionalRoles)) {
      foreach($additionalRoles as $additionalRole) {
        print "Additional role: " . $additionalRole;
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

I tried by checking **'type'** property of permission object. But I get 'user' as its value every time. But the file is already shared to anyone having the link (with Google Drive's permission API and I can see its content). I was expecting 'anyone' as a value of the 'type' property. Can you please let us know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `permissions->list` instead of `permissions->get`. Using `permissions->get` I guess you are sending a permissionId from a user.

Using `permissions->list` you just need to send the fileId and you will receive a list of permissions. Then iterate that list and check if one of them contains `type: anyone` (in your case you can even check `id: anyoneWithLink`).

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list

Comment: Thank you @Rubén López. My problem is solved by using 'list' API instead of 'get' for permissions resource.